# Keep only the lines containing exact number of delimiters

Tags: csv, filter

I have a huge csv file with 10 fields separated by commas. Unfortunately, some lines are malformed and do not contain exactly 10 commas (what causes some problems when I want to read the file into R). How can I filter out only the lines that contain exactly 10 commas?

Comment: your question and the linked  question are *not* the same question. you ask how to how to handle lines with no more or fewer than a certain number of matches, whereas that question requires only a minimum match count. the reality is that question is more easily answered - it doesn't require scanning a line in full, or *(at least, as the `sed` does here)* only as far as one more match than is looked for, though this question does. You should not have closed this.

Comment: actually, looking closer, the asker there *does* want *no more or fewer than* matches. that question needs a new title. but the `grep` answer there is not an acceptable answer for either question...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Another POSIX one:

```
awk -F , 'NF == 11' <file
```

If the line has 10 commas, then there will be 11 fields in this line. So we simply make `awk` use `,` as the field delimiter. If the number of fields is 11, the condition `NF == 11` is true, `awk` then performs the default action `print $0`.

Comment: That's actually the first thing that came to my mind on this question.  I thought it was overkill, but looking at the code...it sure is clearer.  For the benefit of others: `-F` sets the field separator and `NF` refers to the number of fields in a given line.  Since no code block `{statement}` is appended to the condition `NF == 11`, the default action is to print the line.  (@cuonglm, feel free to incorporate this explanation if you like.)

Comment: +1: Very elegant and readable solution that is also very general. I can e.g. found all malformed lines with `awk -F , 'NF != 11' <file`

Comment: @gardenhead: It's easy to get it, as you see the OP said in his comment. I sometime answer from my mobile, so it's difficult to add the details explanation.

Comment: @mikeserv: No, sorry if I made you confused, it's just my bad English. You can't have 11 fields with 1-9 commas.

Comment: oh! of course! right - if they're the splitter they make eleven fields. thanks, man.

Comment: +1 for using the right tool for the job. But I wonder why you '< file', instead of just 'file' to give it as a parameter to awk (which also allows awk to know its filename, etc) ?

Comment: @OlivierDulac: It guards you against file start with `-` or named `-`.

Comment: oh, then   "./file"   instead of  "file"  is the portable way ^^ (as it can be reused in many other situations, so i would rather get used to that one, with or without the "<" (even if the latter makes it superflous)). thx for the reason.

Comment: @OlivierDulac how is that "the portable way"? `<file` is [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07_01), very common and works with any command that takes a filename as input. Are you thinking of `<(command)` instead?

Comment: @terdon: When you say "any command that takes a filename as input", do you mean "any command (program) that takes ***data*** as ***standard** input*?  Because it's not true for "any command that takes a filename as ***a command-line argument***; for example, `cp` and `rm`.  And some commands won't look at stdin unless you give them a **`-`** argument; e.g., `file` and `stat`.

Comment: I compared this to mine and to the grep like: `yes "$(set 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1; IFS=,; for s in 1 2 3; do shift; echo "$*"; done)" | head -n 5000000 | ...cmd... | wc -l` and this was three times faster than the `sed` which completed half again as fast as the `grep`, which took the longest.

Comment: Umm... another check and I may have been hasty - I guess *which* `sed` is very important. While still trailing `awk` by a full 3 seconds to completion, my statically-linked musl libc heirloom `sed` does in 8 seconds what my GNU `sed` requires 18 to do. The variation between `grep`s was not significant, but the `gawk` was still faster than the `mawk`.

Comment: @G-Man I meant any command that takes a file name and then opens it to process the data it contains. I just wanted to point out that there is nothing non-portable about `< file`.

Comment: This solution will not work with empty fields

Comment: @tashuhka: It will, can you show an example?

Comment: @cuonglm True. Thank you for the correction :)

Comment: Or if you have lots of little (or big) files and you want to merge it, you could use a variant of  ``cat `ls *.csv` | awk -F , 'NF == 11' > merged.log`` then change that file's extension to csv when through.

Answer (score 8):

Using `egrep` (or `grep -E` in POSIX):

```
egrep "^([^,]*,){10}[^,]*$" file.csv
```

This filters out anything not containing 10 commas: it matches full lines (`^` at the start and `$` at the end), containing exactly ten repetitions (`{10}`) of the sequence "any number of characters except ',', followed by a single ','" (`([^,]*,)`), followed again by any number of characters except ',' (`[^,]*`).

You can also use the `-x` parameter to drop the anchors:

```
grep -xE "([^,]*,){10}[^,]*" file.csv
```

This is less efficient than [cuonglm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/38906/cuonglm)'s `awk` solution though; the latter is typically six times faster on my system for lines with around 10 commas. Longer lines will cause huge slowdowns.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest `grep` code that will work:

```
grep -xE '([^,]*,){10}[^,]*'
```

Explanation:

`-x` ensures that the pattern must match the *entire* line, rather than just part of it.  This is important so you don't match lines with more than 10 commas.

`-E` means "extended regex", which makes for less backslash-escaping in your regex.

Parentheses are used for grouping, and the `{10}` afterwards means there must be exactly ten matches in a row of the pattern within the parantheses.

`[^,]` is a character class—for instance, `[c-f]` would match any single character that is a `c`, a `d`, an `e` or an `f`, and `[^A-Z]` would match any single character that is NOT an uppercase letter.  So `[^,]` matches any single character except a comma.

The `*` after the character class means "zero or more of these."

So the regex part `([^,]*,)` means "Any character except a comma any number of times (including zero times), followed by a comma" and the `{10}` specifies 10 of these.  Then `[^,]*` to match the rest of the non-comma characters to the end of the line.

Answer (score 5):

```
sed -ne's/,//11;t' -e's/,/&/10p' <in >out
```

That first branches out any line with 11 or more commas, and then prints of what remains only those that match 10 commas.

Apparently I answered this before... Here's a [me-plagiarism](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/183705/52934) from a question looking for exactly 4 occurrences of some pattern:

> You can target `[num]`th occurrence of a pattern with a sed `s///`ubstitution command by just adding the `[num]` to the command. When you `t`est for a successful substitution and don't specify a target `:`label, the `t`est branches out of the script. This means all you have to do is test for `s///5` or more commas, then print what remains.
>
> Or, at least, that handles the lines which exceed your maximum of 4. Apparently you also have a minimum requirement. Luckily, that is just as simple:

```
sed -ne 's|,||5;t' -e 's||,|4p'
```

> ...just replace the 4th occurrence of `,` on a line with itself and tack your `p`rint on to the `s///`ubstitution flags. Because any lines matching `,` 5 or more times have already been pruned, the lines containing 4 `,` matches contain *only* 4.

Comment: @cuonglm - that is what I had actually, at first, but people are always telling me i should write more readable code. since i can read the stuff others dispute as unreadable im not sure what to keep and what to drop...? so i put the second comma.

Comment: @cuonglm - you can mock me - it wont hurt my feelings. i can take a joke. if you were mocking me it was a little funny. its ok - i just wasn't sure and wanted to know. in my opinion, people should be able to laugh at themselves. anyway, i still dont get it!

Comment: Haha, right, it's a very positive thinking. Anyway, it's very funny to chat with you and sometimes, you *stress* my brain.

Comment: It's interesting that in [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255233/38906), if I replace `s/hello/world/2` with `s//world/2`, GNU sed work fine. With two `sed` from heirloom, `/usr/5bin/posix/sed` raise segfault, `/usr/5bin/sed` goes into infinitive loop.

Comment: @mikeserv, in reference to [our earlier discussion about `sed` and `awk`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/254317/135943) (in comments)—I like this answer and upvoted it, but notice the translation of the accepted `awk` answer is: "Print lines with 11 fields" and the translation of this `sed` answer is: "Attempt to remove the 11th comma; skip to next line if you fail.  Attempt to replace the 10th comma with itself; print line if you succeed."  The `awk` answer gives the instructions to the computer just the way you would express them in English.  (`awk` is good for field based data.)

Comment: @Wildcard - I never argued that it wasn't, only that `sed` was more flexible. And it is - you can *skip to next line if it fails* because the tests are your own to construct - you have more control. And so on the next line the field delimiter could change entirely if you like - because you define fields with each match - or even in the middle of this one. It is more basic - more fundamental - and, in my hands at least, far more powerful. I don't see how the points you bring up here are supposed to contradict any I offered there.

Comment: Anyway, I don't consider that English would make a very good programming language.

Comment: @cuonglm - it didn't for me - it processed 5 million lines without issue - several times.

Answer (score 4):

Throwing some short `python`:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python2
with open('file.csv') as f:
    print '\n'.join(line for line in f if line.count(',') == 10)
```

This will read each line and check if the number of commas in the line is equal to 10 `line.count(',') == 10`, if so print it will the line.

Answer (score 2):

And here's a Perl way:

```
perl -F, -ane 'print if $#F==10'
```

The `-n` causes `perl` to read its input file line by line and execute the script given by `-e` on each line. The `-a` turns on automatic splitting: each input line will be split on the value given by `-F` (here, a comma) and saved as the array `@F`.

The `$#F` (or, more generally `$#array`), is the highest index of the array `@F`. Since arrays start at `0`, a line with 11 fields will have an `@F` of `10`. The script, therefore, prints the line if it has exactly 11 fields.

Comment: You could also do `print if @F==11` as an array in a scalar context returns the number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

If fields can contain commas or newlines your code needs to *understand* csv. Example (with three columns):

```
$ cat filter.csv
a,b,c
d,"e,f",g
1,2,3,4
one,two,"three
...continued"

$ cat filter.csv | python3 -c 'import sys, csv
> csv.writer(sys.stdout).writerows(
> row for row in csv.reader(sys.stdin) if len(row) == 3)
> '
a,b,c
d,"e,f",g
one,two,"three
...continued"
```

I suppose that most solutions so far would discard the second and fourth row.

Answer (score 0):

To display those lines **NOT** containing the exact number of delimiters :

```
[ $(awk -F, '!(NF == 11)' <myfile.csv | wc -l) -gt 0 ] && printf "\nPlease maintain the comma separator for the following line(s) in the myfile.csv: \n\n" && awk -F, '!(NF == 11)' <myfile.csv && echo && exit 1
```

Useful for those looking to **validate** their input data files.

This one liner is taken from my open source project called Automated_Quiz, which is hosted here : https://sourceforge.net/projects/automated-quiz/